# The Image won't be displayed for some reason in php

Tags: html, image, filepath

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>    
    </head>
        <body>
        <img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\testfile\Images\img tk01 (2).png" >
        <?php
        echo "hello"
        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Image isn't being displayed on the browser,don't know what is the problem is.This code is placed on a file called trial.php.
The images are kept in a separate folder as mentioned in the path.
Also is there a problem in using bootstrap navbar in PHP?.
Pls help.

Comment: Remember that a website operates on a web server. The user does not know the file path of the system (and for security reasons, should not). You need to serve these files via HTTP from an appropriate public directory.

Comment: browsers don't work on filesystem paths, they work on URLs. If I access your website, can I read from anywhere on your C: drive directly? You'd better hope not, for your sake. Study some examples of img src tags - they generally start with `http` (or are relative links which resolve to a URL starting with `http`).

Comment: Thank you everyone for answering.The problem has been resolved.Cheers

Comment: if you put this file   index.php in c::/xampp/htdocs/testfile/  and your image is in the  folder Images call this image  <img src="Images\img tk01 (2).png" >   and first that call it in browser first:  http://localhost/testfile/Images/img tk01 (2).png   or http://localhost/testfile/Images/img%20tk01%20(2).png    (just in case Images folder isn't under some .htaccess rule ). If that will not work try to rename the photo whithout using spaces like : phototest.png

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, your image won't show because the way you define your path is incorrect. Assuming file is located in the folder one level up from the current folder Try this way `<img src="../Images/img tk01 (2).png" >`

Refer to this article https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: The path to the image is an absolute path. That is not the issue here.